# Template with a parameter pack of interleaved type and non-type parameters

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, non-type

Is there any syntax that allows defining a variadic template that has both type and non-type interleaved parameters. Ideally I would like  to be able to do something like this:

```
template<typename T, template<typename, auto...> typename C, auto ...Pack>
void f2(const C<T, Pack...>& arg)
{
    std::cout << "Called\n";
}
```

With this syntax however, only non-type parameters may follow T, I would like have it work for both type and non-type parameters. I do not want to have to use `integral_constant` either.

Comment: Short Answer: No.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's unfortunate. Do you know of a proposal regarding this?

Comment: I'm not aware of one.

Comment: What about a pack of `duo<typename,auto>`s?

Comment: @O'Neil AFAIK, you can't have a pack of a specific type.

Comment: @NathanOliver Of course, but that will result in `typename...`.

Comment: @O'Neil That's similar to the `integral_constant` solution, it's precisely something that I do not want. But as it is it seems like it is only possible to have either a type pack or a non-type pack.

Comment: Wrap non-types into integral_constants, that would probably be the simplest in current C++.